# How to access Snapshot out of the StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm using **BLOC** to fetch a movie from an API. I'm Able to access the bloc inside the **StreamBuilder** widget, but I also have a **share button** on the **AppBar** that needs the the **movie.slug** to show the share options. But since the AppBar is out of the StreamBuilder, I'm unable to share the link. Is there a way the AppBar can access the StreamBuilder **Snapshot**?

This is the Page code:

```dart
import 'package:cinemax_app/src/blocs/movie_bloc.dart';
import 'package:cinemax_app/src/components/movie/movie_header.dart';
import 'package:cinemax_app/src/models/movie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html_core/flutter_widget_from_html_core.dart';

class MoviePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int movieId;

  MoviePage({ this.movieId });

  @override
  _MoviePageState createState() => _MoviePageState();
}

class _MoviePageState extends State<MoviePage> {
  MovieModel _movie;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    movieBloc.fetchMovie(widget.movieId);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: movieBloc.movie,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  _movie = snapshot.data as MovieModel;

                  return ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      MovieHeader(movie: _movie),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, bottom: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text('Sinopse:', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                            HtmlWidget(
                              _movie.sinopsis,
                              bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                              textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ]
                  );
                }

                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
            AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              actions: <Widget>[
                PopupMenuButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return <PopupMenuItem>[
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Text('Partilhar'),
                          onTap: () {
                            final movieSLug = _movie.slug;

                            // prints: 'https://cinema.com/movie/null';
                            final movieAddress = 'https://cinema.com/movie/${movieSLug}';

                            Share.share(movieAddress);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ];
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get rid of the Stack and make the StreamBuilder the parent of the Scaffold, that way the entire Scaffold including the app bar can access the snapshot.

Like this

```
class MoviePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int movieId;

  MoviePage({this.movieId});

  @override
  _MoviePageState createState() => _MoviePageState();
}

class _MoviePageState extends State<MoviePage> {
  MovieModel _movie;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    movieBloc.fetchMovie(widget.movieId);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    movieBloc.fetchMovie(widget.movieId);

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: movieBloc.movie,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _movie = snapshot.data as MovieModel;

          return Scaffold(
            appBar:  AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0.0,
              actions: <Widget>[
                PopupMenuButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return <PopupMenuItem>[
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          child: Text('Partilhar'),
                          onTap: () {
                            final movieSLug = _movie.slug;

                            // prints: 'https://cinema.com/movie/null';
                            final movieAddress = 'https://cinema.com/movie/${movieSLug}';

                            Share.share(movieAddress);
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ];
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                MovieHeader(movie: _movie),
                Container(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 45, bottom: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Sinopse:',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title),
                      HtmlWidget(
                        _movie.sinopsis,
                        bodyPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                        textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ]),
            ),
          );
        }

        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I din't tried to run your code, but I think this will fail because there will be times when the stream will have no data and the Scaffold should always be returned with no conditionals. I'm wrong?

Comment: Of course. You can take care of the conditionals yourself. I just showed you could put the stream builder above the rest of the widgets.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to check if the snapshot has data in one place, so you could still show other widgets and have some only show when a condition is satisfied.

Comment: What exactly is the current issue?

Comment: How can I get the **movie.slug** loaded by the StreamBuilder in an **AppBar** action?

Comment: Could you try running the code I share? I think it does just that.

Comment: Not working, GestureDetector is not firing after the change.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to write it with mock data and see how it behaves.

Comment: Check out https://gfycat.com/optimalthoroughindigobunting and code here https://pastebin.com/Anf8r8L7

Comment: Both the app bar and the body are getting data from the stream builder and you can be sure the action in the app bar has the data by the snack bar that comes up when it is tapped. Also notice how the UI does not break but instead shows loading indicators if there is no data in the snapshot yet.

Comment: Victor Eronmosele, you were right! It's working now!